# Javascript code to insert text at cursor position in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

### The use case

When I'm typing a query into a search engine, sometimes it's useful to quote
a part of the query, so the engine doesn't bother me with useless suggestions.

### The task

This operation is so frequent, that I want to do this with a shortcut.
The shortcut part isn't the issue, there's a way to assign a shortcut to a bookmarklet.
What I don't know how to do is

1. Get the current text area. The *only* thing I know about it is that the cursor is there.
   I cannot assume any ids etc. Also, I don't want to install any hooks.
2. Insert "", and go backwards one character.

I'm expecting a one/two liner that I can place in a bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution

Since no one wanted to answer, and I'm just a novice in JavaScript,
I decided to see if there's a plugin that does close to what I want.
The choice fell to [Firemacs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemacs/),
since I'm using it anyway.

The code to go backward one char is simplicity itself:

```
goDoCommand('cmd_charPrevious');
```

However, the command to insert text didn't work.
But the command to paste is simple again:

```
goDoCommand('cmd_paste');
```

Now it only remains to put '""' in the clipboard. This one isn't easy:

```
var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
str.data = '""';

var trans = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
trans.addDataFlavor("text/unicode");
trans.setTransferData("text/unicode",str, str.data.length * 2);

var clipid = Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard;
var clip = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"]
    .getService(clipid);
clip.setData(trans,null,clipid.kGlobalClipboard);
```

Then I just patched this code into the extension instead of the "Ctrl-h" binding,
which I don't use. Problem solved. Now I can insert a pair of quotes very fast in Firefox.